# jpa+ejb how to keep entity attached (managed) for multiple requests?

Tags: jpa, ejb

Here's what I tried so far.

I do 2 requests to my singleton. The first request is handled by method firstRequest and it changes the database. The second request is handled by method secondRequest but it does not change the database.

```
@Singleton
public class App{

@Inject DaoHuman daoHuman;
Human human;    

public void firstRequest(){
    human= daoHuman.findById(1);
    human.setAge(3);
}

public void secondRequest(){
    human.setAge(99);
}
```

---

```
@Stateful
public class DaoHuman{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
```

My problem is the entity becomes detached (unmanaged) after the first request. So it never gets the second request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extended persistence context defined for your Stateful Session Bean and indeed after `daoHuman.findById(1)` (The code for this is not shown but I assume that it is `em.find(Humand.class, id))` is called, the human with Id=1 will become a managed entity and tracked by the extended persistence context.

Furthermore, because you have an *Extended* persistence context this context will last for the life of the Stateful Session Bean, and the human entity will remain managed during muliple client calls (the conversation).

That's all good. However, your Singleton is stateless so when you make your second request, human is not initialised.

You must also bear in mind that your extended persistence context will only be associated with the current transaction when a call is made to the Stateful Session Bean where the EntityManager is defined. This does not happen with `secondRequest()` so when the transaction completes, no persistence context is flushed/persisted to the DB.

A simple way to use the managed instance across multiple calls would be to store the entity on the Stateful Session Bean instance when the bean is first initialised.
I’ve preserved you singleton/Stateful session bean structure in the code below. Depending on requirements, I'd be tempted to make entity updates on the session bean.

```
@Singleton
public class App{

@Inject DaoHuman daoHuman;
Human human;    

    Public void init(int humanId){
        daoHuman.init(humanId);
}

    public void firstRequest(){
// Making the call to daoHuman.getHuman() both returns the mnaged entity and
// causes the persistence context to be associated with the current  
// transation, so when this method call ends, the context will be 
// Depending on requirementsflushed/committed.
        human= daoHuman.getHuman();
        human.setAge(3);
}

    public void secondRequest(){
        human= daoHuman.getHuman();
        human.setAge(99);
}

@Stateful
public class DaoHuman{
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;
Human human;

    public void Init(int humanId){  
// em.find() will ensure the found entity becomes managed - part of the
// persistene context, placing it on the instance variable ensures    
// the managed entity is available over multple client invocatons (converstion)
        human = em.find(Human.class, humanId)
}
    public Human getHuman(){
        return human;
}
```